# Fatal Error gradle-3.5.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: flutter, dart

[Fatal Error] gradle-3.5.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Required by:
> > project :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
> > > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 27s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Stack overflow is a platform for getting answers to your code related questions. We generally require you to upload some of the work you have done including the code that you have wrote and caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to Your Project root Folder ,
than go to Android -> Gradle -> `Delete Gradle FOlder`
Now Restart the Project . It will solve your Problem